# How to restrict some pages from using the layout page in Angular JS SPA?

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I don't want to use the layout page for login page where as all other pages in application have to use the layout page. How to achieve this in Angular JS SPA?

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible and most common solution is to use composite templates with ui-router. This allows you to define a top level login that uses one template, and then another top-level whose child states will all inherit another template.

Comment: can you provide some link for this